# Warning: Cannot modify header information (I deleted all white space in php tags)

Tags: header

I have the business logic and html together. I eliminated all the white space and am still getting this error. I am not sure how to eliminate this. Any tips on how to fix this error. Thank you for your help.

```
<?php 
require 'core/init.php';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" >
<title>Activate</title>
</head>
<body>  
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h1>Activate your account</h1>
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty ($_GET['success']) === true) {
        ?>
        <h3>Thank you, we've activated your account. You're free to log in!</h3>
        <?php   
    } else if (isset ($_GET['email'], $_GET['email_code']) === true) {

    $email      =trim($_GET['email']);
    $email_code =trim($_GET['email_code']);

        if ($users->email_exists($email) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Sorry, we couldn\'t find that email address.';
        } else if ($users->activate($email, $email_code) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Sorry, we couldn\'t activate your account.';
        }
     if(empty($errors) === false){
    echo '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $errors) . '</p>';  
     } else {
            header('Location: activate.php?success');
            exit();
        }
        } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because your output contains HTML before you call header(); You can do:

- Proper handle HTML in PHP (preferred) or
- [Buffer your output](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Answer (score 0):

There are some outputs that shouldn't be made before calling **header()**. One of those are RAW HTML areas before  code.

See this article for detailed Information:
[How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)